# How can I change this Html Form to Yii framework

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii

I'm having some problem when try to change this html form to Yii framework.
In my home.html:

```
   <!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Demo Active Table</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layout">
        <header>
            <h2>Edit</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="table">

            <fieldset>
                <table class="table_content" id="table_content">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell1" ><input type="text" value="0"></td>
                        <td class="cell2" ><input type="text"></td>
                        <td class="cell3" ><input type="text"></td>

                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell1" ><input type="text" value="1"></td>
                            <td class="cell2" ><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="cell3" ><input type="text"></td>
                            <td class="cell4" ><input type="button" value="Delete" class="button" id="delete"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="footer">
                <input type="button" value="Add" class="button w128" id="add">
                <input type="button" value="Sort" class="button w128" id="sort">
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <input type="button" value="Save" class="button w128" id="add">
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my home.js

```
    var index = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').on('click',addRow);
    $('fieldset input[type="button"]').on('click',delRow);
});

function addRow(){
    //prevent add more row
    if(count('tr')==11){
        return false;
    }
    //set index
    setIndex();
    //add row
    var html = '<tr>';
        html +='<td class="cell1" ><input type="text" value="'+index+'"></td>';
        html +='<td class="cell2" ><input type="text"></td>';
        html +='<td class="cell3" ><input type="text"></td>';
        html +='<td class="cell4" ><input type="button" value="Delete" class="button" id="delete"></td>';
        html +='</tr>';
    $('#table_content tbody').append(html);
    //ini onclick for new delete button
    $('fieldset input[type="button"]').on('click',delRow);
}

function delRow(){ 
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    parent.remove();
};

function count(tab){
    var count = 0;
    $(tab).each(function(){
        count++;
    });
    return count;
}

function setIndex(){
    var lastIndex = parseInt($("tr:last").find('input').val());
    index = lastIndex +1;
}
```

Suppose I have a table in my database with 4 columns:

> - ID int (primary key auto_increment)
> - text1 varchar
> - text2 varchar
> - prior int

*'prior' is that when i click button 'add', it auto increases in the first column.
The button 'sort' is when i click 'sort': the form is auto sort by 'prior' ASC
The button 'save' is that when i click 'save', all the rows will be save to database.
Can someone help me, 
Thanks so much.*

Comment: You don't ask people to write your code for you, that's how.

Comment: But honestly, at least give it a go and post back with your errors, they did invent documentation for a reason.